# Make Django REST to call create method of first class from retrieve method of another class

Tags: django, rest, django-rest-framework, django-rest-viewsets

Below code calls the retrieve method and works fine

```
class SomeWorkflow(ViewSet):
    serializer_class = SomeWorkflowSerializer

    def retrieve(self, request, pk):
        response = OtherWorkflow.as_view({'get': 'retrieve'})(request._request, 'some_id').data
```

Now I want to call the **OtherWorkflowSerializer** class's create method. The create method also takes some parameters like {'id': 1, 'file_path': '/foo/bar/file.txt'}

Comment: Could you add a little more context? Why would you want to create something from a GET request?

Comment: There are four to five classes and I want to call them via loop to automate the functionality, also it is not necessary to use GET, I can use POST request also to call other POST methods of the classes. It can be either way.